# HTML with SVG tags and CSS -> Android SVG Render BUG

Tags: android, html, css, svg, render

Currently working on a website which works fine in every browser I tested it. It only doesn't work in a any browser which is run on Android device - Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 SM-T580 16Gb.

This is a screenshot of the problem:

- [Android Render SVG Bug 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEkRJ.png),
- [Android Render SVG Bug 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX4aJ.png)

Another one SVG [works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMO3R.png) on this device.

On Desktop devices, iPads and iPhones there is no such bug. Here is the same SVG (as Bug 1 showing) [Desktop 
 print-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOjs1.png).

**Html code, SVG code added using jquery, also I add the mask and transform:**

```css
#svg_plan_handler {
   height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<div id="svg_plan_handler">
    <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
            xml:space="preserve" 
            width="100%" height="100%" 
            version="1.1" 
            style="shape-rendering: geometricPrecision; text-rendering: geometricPrecision; fill-rule: evenodd; clip-rule: evenodd; height: 658px; transform: scale(6.98011, 6.98011) translate(-255px, -42px);" 
            viewBox="0 0 36872 9821" 
            class="animation">
            <defs>
             <style type="text/css">
             <![CDATA[
              .str0 {stroke:black;stroke-width:112.75;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round}
              .str1 {stroke:black;stroke-width:113.07;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round}
              .str5 {stroke:black;stroke-width:119.54;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round}
              .str4 {stroke:black;stroke-width:119.82;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round}
              .str2 {stroke:black;stroke-width:120.08;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round}
              .str3 {stroke:black;stroke-width:120.29;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round}
              .fil4 {fill:none}
              .fil6 {fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero}
              .fil5 {fill:black}
              .fil2 {fill:#029E21}
              .fil1 {fill:#3FA4FF}
              .fil0 {fill:#A50F02}
              .fil7 {fill:#CCCCCC}
              .fil3 {fill:#FF6600}
              ]]>
            </style>
            </defs>
            <polygon id="perimetr_f_1_kv_17" class="fil7 perimetr_kv" points="32140,5828 32140,4989 27595,4989 27595,7642 30702,7642 30702,6464 30702,6459 30707,6459 32072,6459 32072,5833 32072,5828 32077,5828 "></polygon>
            <g id="entrance" style="mask: url("#planmaskingapartments");">
               <g id="f_1">
                  <path id="f_1_entrance_1" class="fil4 str0" d="M16886 7882l1477 0m0 0l0 -34m0 0l-1477 0m0 0l0 34m-16676 -3653l1022 0m435 0l193 0m77 0l1380 
                     ... bla-bla ...
                  72l0 -144m893 144l0 -144"/>
               </g>
            </g>
            <path id="bg_f_1_kv_17" class="fil3 selected" d="M31300 5876l697 0 -2 430 82 0 0 158 -263 1 0 -106 -514 0 0 -483zm-593 -892l0 165 58 0 0 -165 492 0 0 1481 -492 0 0 -733 0 -121 -58 0 0 121 -1390 0 0 -748 1390 0zm593 849l0 -849 845 0 0 849 -845 0zm-1983 1814l0 -1886 1390 0 0 1886 -1390 0zm-1727 0l0 -2663 1669 0 0 2663 -1669 0z"></path>

          <mask id="planmaskingapartments">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#perimetr_f_1_kv_17" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="100%" stroke="#000000"></use>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#perimetr_f_1_kv_17" stroke-width="3%" stroke="#777777"></use>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#bg_f_1_kv_17" stroke="#c1f0d3" stroke-width="1.5%"></use>
          </mask>
        </svg>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Have some body any idea, how to fix it?

Comment: It only fails on that one device?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau i think, some other android device can give same bug

Comment: Can you work out what is common about those devices?  Also, please post a [mcve].  We can't help determine what is wrong, or how to work around it,  without being to see and test the problem.

Comment: If you want help, please try to reduce your SVG to the most minimal version that still reproduces the problem. We are all busy people. That's why we have the [mcve] rule.